# Facebook : App extension in iOS 8

Tags: facebook, ios8, installation, ios-app-extension

I want a small clarification, please help.
In **iOS8 UIActivityViewController** will list the sharing sites like **Vimeo Vine** etc. If Vimeo app is installed on the device it is listed even if it is not logged in device's system settings . Why not **Facebook** is listed like Vimeo if Facebook account is not logged in device's system settings and **app is installed** on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook don't include share extension. Hence it wont be listed in UIActivityViewController. To be listed in UIActivityViewController app need to include share extension. Vine Vimeo do include share extension.